# Handle ctrl +d programmatically?

Tags: c, perl, shell

I am trying to execute the following perl script.

```
  ##some code
  $command = "nail -s this is a test  $email";
  system($command);
  ##some code
```

when I run this script, it hangs until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> I get the desired result. My question is how can I hardcode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in my script?

Comment: do you mean "mail -s..." instead of nail ?

Comment: It hangs because the `mail` program (I guess you meant `mail`?) expects input from standard input. The CTRL-D combination means end-of-file and the `mail` program checks for that to end the input.

Comment: its not `mail`... its `nail`...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you call `mailx`. `nail` ist most likely an alias. It expects input from STDIN, which is ended with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. You could workaround like this to send an empty mail:

```
$command = 'echo "" | nail -s SUBJECT ' . $email;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mail program expects an `.` on a line alone to show it is the end of the message
Just make sure your $email contains a `\n.` and it should no longer hang.

Answer (score 0):

#### The usual solution is to redirect it to read from /dev/null

Try to use this :

```
mail -s "Hello Test" -a Attachment email-address  </dev/null
```

or,  if you have any email body

```
mail -s "Hello Test" -a Attachment email-address  <emailbodyfile.txt
```